# Only finitely many reduced cubics with given discriminant?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

I call a cubic form $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ (with $a,b,c\in{\mathbb Q}$)
 reduced when $a=0$. The discriminant is then $-4b^3-27c^2$. For
 a fixed $t\in{\mathbb Q}$, is there an algorithm to decide if
 there are finitely or inifinitely many pairs $(b,c)\in{\mathbb Q}^2$
 such that $-4b^3-27c^2=t$ ? 
    By analogy with Mordell's equation, I would expect that there are
    only finitely solutions for any $t$.

Comment: I would expect the opposite: For "most" t, the elliptic curve $y^2 = \frac{4}{27} x^3 + t$ should have nonzero rank and thus infinitely many $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points.

Comment: Take $n$ be any number from [OEIS A002152](http://oeis.org/A002152) and let $t = 108n$, you will find equation $4b^3 + 27c^2 + t = 0$ has infinitely many rational solutions in $(b,c)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're wrong with what you call Mordell's equation and if not, I apologize, please.

What you want, indeed, is to find out the cardinality of the set of rational points of the cubic $$4x^3+27y^2+t=0$$  This is a great unsolved problem and it is just known that there may be the following three circumstances: no solution, finitely solutions (all are torsion points) and infinitely solutions.

Is anything else with respect to find rational points of an elliptic cubic (apart from the great Mordell’s  teorem of the finite basis which does not give any method of determination of the rational points).

Comment: After half a glass of wine, I think I disagree. Doesn’t the experimental evidence seem to show that in any “reasonable” arithmetic family of elliptic curves, the rank is zero half the time and $1$ half the time?

Comment: Dear Lubin: The family $x^3+y^3=k$ is quite “reasonable”. It was deeply studied by Selmer who, I think, could not have imagined that for $k=13293998056584952174157235$ the rank is $11$ (Noam D. Elkies and Nicholas F. Rogers, from Harvard University). You surely know that a very important conjecture is that the range of elliptic curves is unbounded. Regards.

Comment: I certainly do know the conjecture, @Ataulfo, and i devoutly hope that it’s true. You didn’t say, though, what the statistics are for this family, which I have to say that I’m not at all well acquainted with.